# Error handling with Spring CommandName

Tags: spring

when using Spring framework and binding a form on a commandName object to add let's say a person with the following fields.

```
<form method="POST" action="addPerson.htm" commandName="person">
            <input id="firstname" name="firstname"value="${person.firstname}"/>
            <br>
             <input id="name" name="name" value="${person.name}"/>
             <br>
             <input id="age" name="age" value="${person.age}"/>
</form>
```

On the server I've got the following code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addPerson", method={RequestMethod.POST})
    public String addPerson(@ModelAttribute(value="person") Person p){
        service.addPerson(p);
        return "redirect:/overview.htm";
    }
```

How do I do error handling with this, so let's say for example the age must be a positive number and firstname can be left empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new Validator class, implementing `Validator` interface.
Your validator can be something like this:

```
    public class PersonValidator implements Validator {
        public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
            return Person.class.equals(clazz);
        }

        public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {

            Person person=(Person)target;

            if ( person.getAge() < 0 ) {
                 errors.rejectValue("age", "age_positive");
                 // Or you can use this approach as well to parametrize the error message:
                //errors.rejectValue("age", "age_positive", ArrayParametersIfNeeded, "DefaultMessage");
            }

        }

    }
```

You also need to have a error.properties file to hold the errors messages allowing i18n. 
You can have all needed information about validators here: [Validators](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html)

When you have it, you need to create the initBinder method in the controller:

```
@InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.addValidators(yourValidator);
    }
```

Then, in the controller method, you can pass this additional parameter: `BindingResult result` and there you will have the information of the errors if you need it.
Also, you need to add this bit to the form:

```
<form:errors path="age"/></c:set>
```

Below your `<input id="age" name="age" value="${person.age}"/>`

I suggest you to change your `<input>` elements for the `<form:input>` tag.